# Why my pop up is closed immediately?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I use Jquery UI to open a pop up on a click but this pop up is closed immediately.I don't understand why?
Here is my code:

```
function openPopUp() {
    //  alert("Handler for .click() called.");
        $("#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog("destroy");
        $("#select-method").dialog({
            modal : true,
            height: 573,
            width: 766 ,
            buttons : {
                Exporter : function() {
                    //$(this).dialog("close");
                     alert("Exporter");
                    // close the dialog
                },
                'Etat de surveillance' : function() {
                    //$(this).dialog("close");
                     alert("Etat de surveillance");
                    // close the dialog
                },
                Annuler : function() {
                    //$(this).dialog("close");
                     alert("Annuler");
                    // close the dialog
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

The code html is:

```
<div id="other" class="popLink">This is text
        <a href="" class="popLink" onClick="openPopUp();">
        Click to open pop up
        </a>
</div>

<div class="noDisplay">
        <div id="select-method" title="selection des méthodes et calcul des provisions">My pop upis opened
            </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: most likely the anchor tag's default behavior is causing the page to refresh and/or navigate somewhere, which would close the jquery dialog as it exists in the same DOM. try preventing the default behavior of the click.

Comment: What i have to add. I am not good in jQuery

Comment: Try to use `<a href="#" class="popLink" onClick="openPopUp();">`.

Comment: Please provide code/examples/comments in English only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the one comment says, try something like this:

```
onclick="openPopUp();return false;"
```

Although it would make sense, since you're already using jQuery, to bind the event with jQuery, not inline HTML. Instead of specifying the `onclick` attribute, try this in `$(document).ready`:

```
$(".popLink").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Either call openPopUp or copy/paste the code from that function into here - depends on how you actually use openPopUp throughout your whole site
});
```

But at the same time, you have something weird in your HTML - nested divs with the same class "popLink". Which means that if you used my code above, when you click on the inner one, the `showPopUp` will execute twice (because of propagation). So I guess I would technically use this binding:

```
$("#other").on("click", ".popLink", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Other code
});
```

This technically binds the `click` event to the element `#other`, but only is executed if caused by an element inside of it that has the class "popLink". There are several other ways to target the `<a>` you want, so it depends on if the code you provided is an example or is real.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
$('.popLink').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  openPopUp();
});
```